How can we deploy ReactJS application on WildFly 27 server?
ReactJS web application requires routing as every request will be redirected to the index.html file.
So, how can we configure routing for the reactjs application when we are going to deploy it on WildFly which is an application server? Also is it recommended to deploy the ReactJS application on WildFly?
The steps I tried for the above question are:
I have added the ReactJS source code to the Maven project.
The routing was handled using "web.xml" by redirecting to the index.html when we got a 404-Not Found error.
To access the project when deployed on WildFly, I have configured the BrowserRouter in ReactJS source code which will be used in pom.xml to access using Public URL.
In ReactJS:
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || 'myapp'}>
The ReactJS application is deployed on WildFly by creating a war package that includes the build.
The URL to access the app will be "https://ip-address/myapp"
The above configuration is working fine.
But, is this the correct way of configuration and deployment?
What are the other ways to configure and deploy?
